# Externalizing tikz with precompiled preamble

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, preamble

This is a very special case, I guess, but it's what I need:

```
%&Testing
\documentclass{article}
\endofdump
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=x axis label,ylabel=y axis label]
    \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to be able to switch tikz on or off without having to recompile the preamble, hence the \endofdump. I created the header using MiKTeX and

```
etex -job-name=Testing -initialize "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx Testing.tex
```

When I then compile Testing.tex, I get this error message:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Testing-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjo
b{Testing}\input{Testing}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'Testing-fig
ure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).
```

Checking the respective log file (`Testing-figure0.log`), I find this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \endofdump 

l.3 \endofdump
```

I was wondering how I could fix this. It seems that the externalized tikz job inputs the preamble, but does not use the custom format. Hence, it can't understand \endofdump.

I found that this works (this may already be the answer).

```
%&Testing
\documentclass{article}
\ifcsname tikzexternalrealjob\endcsname\else\endofdump\fi
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=x axis label,ylabel=y axis label]
    \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the macro that contains the external pdflatex call to instead call

```
etex '&mylatexformat'
```

I needed the following commandline to make the format

```
etex --job-name=testing --ini "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx testing.tex
```

once the format is made, add the following so tikz externalize uses it

```
\def\zzz#1 #2\relax{%
\expandafter\def\csname pgfk@/tikz/external/system call\endcsname{etex '&mylatexformat' #2}%
}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\zzz\csname pgfk@/tikz/external/system call\endcsname\relax
```

so this runs without error

```
%&Testing
\documentclass{article}
\endofdump
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\def\zzz#1 #2\relax{%
\expandafter\def\csname pgfk@/tikz/external/system call\endcsname{etex '&mylatexformat' #2}%
}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\zzz\csname pgfk@/tikz/external/system call\endcsname\relax
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=x axis label,ylabel=y axis label]
    \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the generic `\ifdefined\endofdump\endofdump\else\fi`?